# How to run nightwatch against a Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, nightwatch.js

A friend pointed me to nightwatchjs today (http://nightwatchjs.org/) and I wanted to have a play around to see how easy it is to use against our Google App Engine application.

I'm trying to create a gradle task that invokes the nightwatch command, but first ensures that appengine is running by invoking the appengineRun command.

Currently, the task looks something like this:

```
task nightwatch(){
    tasks.appengineDownloadSdk.execute();
    tasks.compileJava.execute();
    tasks.processResources.execute();
    tasks.classes.execute();
    tasks.appengineEnhance.execute();
    tasks.war.execute();
    tasks.appengineExplodeApp.execute();
    tasks.appengineRun.execute();
    exec {
        executable "bash"
        args "-c","nightwatch src/functionalTest/nightwatch/nightwatch.js"
    }
    tasks.appengineStop.execute();
}
```

My first thought is: *There must be an easier way!?!?*

So, my questions are actually this:

1. This task appears to work ok, except that it stops at appengineRun because it's not running in daemon mode. How can I make it do this?
2. If this isn't actually the best way to do this, then what is?

If this doesn't work, I'm going back to using Selenium in JUnit tests. For those who are interested: I don't need to jump through the same hoops with Selenium/JUnit, because the appengineFunctionalTest gradle task ensures that the dev app is already running.

Thanks for any help that people can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess all you need is to run it *after* appengineRun? you just need to add `dependsOn: appengineRun` then.

Also, all this commands inside `task` are executed when gradle reads your script, not when taks is executed. it's a configuration block. You need to use `doLast {}` there to setup code that should be executed.

Try this:

```
appengine {
    daemon = false
}

task appengineDaemon() {
  doLast {
    appengine {
       daemon = true
    }
  }
}
appengineRun.mustRunAfter(appengineDaemon)

task nightwatch(dependsOn: [appengineRun, appengineDaemon]) {
  doLast {
    exec {
        executable "bash"
        args "-c","nightwatch src/functionalTest/nightwatch/nightwatch.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This certainly does look cleaner, but unfortunately nothing runs after appengineRun. I believe this is because it's not running in daemon mode?

Comment: oh yeah, i think you need to do put `daemon=true` into `appengine {}` config

Comment: That works, but it's not ideal, as now when I run the appengineRun task to check some development work that also is affected by that setting. I can't see log output etc to the console. Is there any way to set this daemon setting just for this task?

Comment: take a look at updated answer. i didn't try though, but it should be something like this

Comment: That works, but the appengineDaemon task needs renaming to something that doesn't start with "appengine". Thanks!